# Why does my website flash unstyled content?

Tags: html, css, astrojs

I am hosting the following astro project on netlify, and every time i refresh a page i get a flash of unstyled content. any help would be appreciated.

Im handling styles using tailwindCss and the main layout for the page is:

```
---
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.svelte";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.astro";
---
<style is:global>
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
</style>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>JMJM</title>
        <script is:inline>
            let domReady = (cb) => {
                document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete'
                    ? cb()
                    : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cb);
            };

            domReady(() => {
                // Display body when DOM is loaded
                document.body.style.visibility = 'visible';
            });
            const html = document.querySelector("html");
            const theme = (() => {
              if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("theme")) {
                return localStorage.getItem("theme");
              }
              if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
                return "dark";
              }
              return "light";
            })();

            if (theme === "light") {
              html.classList.remove("dark");
            } else {
              html.classList.add("dark");
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
          </script>
    </head>
    <body style="hidden" class="bg-snow2 text-night0 dark:bg-night0 dark:text-snow2">       
        <script>0</script>
        <Navbar client:load />
        <div class="max-w-[1080px] mx-auto">
            <slot />
        </div>
        <Footer />
        <noscript><style>body { visibility: visible; }</style></noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Full Source: https://github.com/jmjaimesmendoza/portfolio

Answer (score 0):

Astro generates seperate pages for every url. So, when you visit a new page it has to load a new css file. If loading that css file takes a bit of time you might see a flash of unstyled content. You could switch your styling to inline but that would require you to move away front tailwindcss